# PHP : add methods calling $this to existing classes

Tags: php, class, dynamic, methods, dynamic-programming

I have a container class :

```
class ContainerClass {
    var $subobj;
    var $myName;

    function __construct($val, $name)
    {
        $this->myName = $name;
        $this->subobj = new ItemClass ($val);
    }

    function getItem()
    {
        return ($this->subobj);
    }
}
```

and a class :

```
class ItemClass {
    var $value;

    function __construct($val)
    {
        $this->value = $val;
    }
}
```

These two classes are member of a hypothetical library, that can be used in many projects simply by using an `include` call.

In my projects, I need to do some specific display, so **for each project**, I'd like, without modifying the library source code, add methods like these one (with project specific contents) :

## Project 1

### For `ContainerClass`:

```
function getDisplay () {
   return ($myName . " : " . $this->subobj->getDisplay());
}
```

### For `ItemClass`:

```
function getDisplay () {
   return (/* some display */ $this->value);
}

function getDisplayAlone () {
   return (/* some display */"<DIV>" .  $this->value . "</DIV>");
}
```

## Project 2

### For ContainerClass:

```
function getDisplay () {
   if ($this->value == 5) return ($myName . " : " . $this->subobj->getDisplay());
   return ("No luck !");
}
```

### For `ItemClass`:

```
function getDisplay () {
   return (/* some display */"Go to hell !");
}

function getDisplayAlone () {
   return (/* some display */"<DIV>What's up doc ?</DIV>");
}
```

And be able to call these from my main php file from each project :

```
include "mylibrary.php";
$obj = new ContainerClass (10, "Me");
$obj->getDisplay();
$obj->getItem()->getDisplayAlone();
```

I've found many tips and tricks to add methods to classes and objects, but they either do not work on php5, do not allow the use of `$this` inside the methods, or does not work at all.

Can someone help me to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`extends`](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php)

### Project 1

```
class ProjectItemClass extends ContainerClass {

    function getDisplay () {
        return (/* some display */ $this->value);
    }

    function getDisplayAlone () {
         return (/* some display */"<DIV>" .  $this->value . "</DIV>");
    }

}

class ProjectContainerClass extends ContainerClass {

    public function __construct($val, $name) {
        $this->myName = $name;
        $this->subobj = new ProjectItemClass ($val);
    }

    function getDisplay () {
        return ($myName . " : " . $this->subobj->getDisplay());
    }

}
```

### Project 2

```
class ProjectItemClass extends ContainerClass {

    function getDisplay () {
        return (/* some display */"Go to hell !");
    }

    function getDisplayAlone () {
        return (/* some display */"<DIV>What's up doc ?</DIV>");
    }

}
class ProjectContainerClass extends ContainerClass {

    public function __construct($val, $name) {
        $this->myName = $name;
        $this->subobj = new ProjectItemClass ($val);
    }

    function getDisplay () {
        if ($this->value == 5) return ($myName . " : " . $this->subobj->getDisplay());
        return ("No luck !");
    }

}
```

Make sure you include/require these new classes after the original classes, and then utilize them like so:

```
$obj = new ProjectContainerClass (10, "Me");
$obj->getDisplay();
$obj->getItem()->getDisplayAlone();
```

Note the overriding `__construct` to ensure that `ProjectItemClass` is used instead of `ItemClass`. You could also use a `parent` call to ensure that any changes to the extended class' construct are still utilized (but `$this->subobj` would just get called twice.)

```
public function __construct($val, $name) {
    parent::__construct($val, $name);
    $this->subobj = new ProjectItemClass($val);
}
```

Comment: Smart, the overriding constructor ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this will be your libary classes:

```
class ContainerClass 
{
    protected $subobj; //Must be protected to be accessable for the child classes
    protected $myName; //Must be protected to be accessable for the child classes

    function __construct($val, $name)
    {
        $this->myName = $name;
        $this->subobj = new ItemClass ($val);
    }

    function getItem()
    {
        return ($this->subobj);
    }

}

class ItemClass  {

    private $value;

    function __construct($val)
    {
        $this->value = $val;
    }

}
```

If you want to implement different functions for each project you need to override your libary classes. So e.g. `Project1ItemClass` extends the libary `ItemClass` class. Here is an example:

```
class Project1ItemClass extends ItemClass {

    function getDisplay () {
       return (/* some display */ $this->value);
    }

    function getDisplayAlone () {
       return (/* some display */"<DIV>" .  $this->value . "</DIV>");
    }

}

class Project1ContainerClass extends ContainerClass {

    //Override the constructor cause you want to create a project 1 specific ItemClass
    function __construct($val, $name)
    {
        $this->myName = $name;
        $this->subobj = new Project1ItemClass ($val);
    }

    function getDisplay () {
       return ($this->myName . " : " . $this->subobj->getDisplay());
    }
}
```

This example below will print: `qwe : asd`

```
$Project1ContainerClass = new Project1ContainerClass("asd","qwe");
echo $Project1ContainerClass->getDisplay();
```

Note that you should override your constructor in the project specific `ContainerClass` because you are creating a new instance of `ItemClass` in it. If you don't override the constructor you are creating an instance of `ItemClass` while your intention is an instance of `Project1ItemClass`.

Comment: `protected` works, but is not necessary with OP's original code. See [test here](http://codepad.org/P9M7OiO0). So modifying the library code is unnecessary unless it was declared explicitly [as `private` variables](http://codepad.org/Tp83hDA8). OP also requests explicitly that the library source code does _not_ get modified.

Comment: You are right on that, but what i understood was he don't want to change the libary code for each project. He can make his variables protected and never have to change the code again. My opinion is that public variables in a class are a bad thing. So that's why i make it protected instead of the default public.

Comment: That's true. I don't want to rewrite the code for each project, assuming that I don't necessary know it or have control on it. Most of all, there can be many methods that uses ItemClass. If the deal is to rewrite each method that uses the Item class, it would be quicker and safer to duplicate the library for each project and just add the added methods inside it. And that is what I want to avoid.

Comment: Maybe, but if you change the libary once you can always use it for all the different projects in the future. Note that it's not always neccesary to override the `ItemClass`, cause maybe you don't need changes on that in a certain project. Also if you override the `ItemClass` you do not need to override each method, but only the methods that are different from the default behaviour.